# implement webcache as web application

Tags: java, tomcat, caching

looking for someone to verify whether this approach is good or not . let say i have web app A run on tomcat. By deploying one webcache web app on the same tomcat. will that minimum the likelyhood that my web app crash due to overload by web visitors?   if yes, what webcache should i used to implement this technique? or should i forget about webcache deploy this way and user service like akamai instead..?     low cost is my main priority.  looking forward to hear from you all

Answer (score 1):

By duplicating on the same server/machine you gain nothing. When many users rush to the website, you would need more system resources to serve them and since these are shared by all web apps the second installation will be in as bad situation as the first one.

To properly cluster a web application you need more servers. You install Tomcat and your web application in each one and then use a load balancer to share the traffic. This is usually implemented with Apache Web Server and `mod_proxy` or `mod_jk`. Of course you need to pay for the extra server. One solution would be to deploy your app in a cloud environment (like Amazon EC2) and start the second server only when needed.

Another solution is to scale up, that is use a more powerful machine.

Comment: if for low cost reason, insist to deploy webcache on same web application server. which webcache web app should i use? any recommendation?